# Где смотреть логи Grafana cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, облако, grafana

Есть аккаунт на https://grafana.com/ при попытке подключить модуль CloudWatch используя user/key/arn выдает ошибку при сохранении и проверке.

Кто-то уже использовал облачное решении от Grafana, как можно отлаживать и смотреть логи ошибок?